# How sizeof(std::cout) is 140 whereas sizeof(std::string) is only 4?

Tags: c++, sizeof, cout

Consider following program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout<<sizeof(std::string)<<'\n';
    std::cout<<sizeof(std::ostream)<<'\n';
    std::cout<<sizeof(std::istream)<<'\n';
    std::cout<<sizeof(std::cout);
}
```

The output on my compiler(g++ 4.8.1) is

```
4

140

144

140
```

The output really confuses me. Why sizeof `string` class is only 4 bytes & for ostream & istream it gives 140 & 144 bytes respectively? The `sizeof(std::cout)`is 140 bytes that is same as `sizeof(std::ostream)`. So, I think because `cout` object is of type `ostream` that's why I am getting output same here. right? Are these sizes compiler dependent?

Comment: Why do you expect any particular relationship between `sizeof(string)` and `sizeof(cout)`? What possible insight do you hope to gain by comparing the two?

Comment: @Downvoters: Why downvotes? What's wrong?

Comment: As Igor points out, the question isn't very useful, hence downvotes.

Comment: @PravasiMeet Because the question makes no sense. Your question boils down to "why is the size of A different from the size of an unrelated type B".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it comes down to the fact that an iostream has quite a bit of state to store, but a string has very little.

Nonetheless, the idea of a string having a size of only 4 is a little surprising (at least to me). I'd normally expect something like 12 for a 32-bit implementation, or 24 for a 64-bit version.

In particular, a string will typically contain three things: a pointer to the actual buffer to hold the data (typically allocated on the free store), a size_t to contain the size of that buffer, and a size_t to contain the number of characters currently being stored. In a typical case, each of those will be 32-bits on a 32-bit implementation and 64-bits on a 64-bit implementation.

It's entirely possible to justify a string object that's somewhat larger than that as well--for example, it's fairly common to store the data for a small string directly in the string object itself ("short string optimization"). In this case, you might have space for (up to) something like 20 characters in the string object itself, which will typically increase its size still further.

Comment: The OP is using GCC 4.8, so this is the reference-counted copy-on-write implementation.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: why sizeof std::cout,std::cin is compiler dependent? Do all the compilers implement stream objects differently?

Comment: @PravasiMeet: They don't have to, but they're free to do so.

Comment: @PravasiMeet: It means instead of the string object containing any information directly, each string object you create is just a pointer to the actual information. What it points at contains a count of the number of string objects referring to it, so it destroys itself when there are no more. When copy a string, it just increments the count and gives  back another pointer to the same data (and only copies the actual data when/if you modify it). This implementation was popular decades ago, but has lost popularity with multi-threading (and as of C++11 is no longer officially allowed).